# I got this error while doing simulating a network when building a blockchain

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, substrate-node, blockchain

I encountered the following error while simulating a network when running the command:

```
./target/release/node-template purge-chain --base-path /tmp/alice --chain local
```

i got error indicating `/tmp/alice/chains/local_testnet/db/full` did not exist.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eenKM.png]

Answer (score 1):

The `purge-chain` command is trying to remove the folder `/tmp/alice/chains/local_testnet/db/full` by default, and you don't have anything there.
You can explore where are you keeping this data `cd tmp && ls`

When you have it you can indicate the path in the flag `--base-path` or delete the folder manually `rm -r path`

In case you are running the node with the flag `--tmp` it uses temporary storage and deletes the folder when you stop the chain, which means when you manually go to purge the data, the data has been already deleted.

```
--tmp: Use temporary storage for chain data (the chain state is deleted on exit)
```

The `--dev` flag also set the `--tmp` flag

```
--dev
          Specify the development chain. This flag sets `--chain=dev`, `--force-authoring`, `--rpc-cors=all`, `--alice`, and `--tmp` flags, unless explicitly overridden
```

Comment: I  checked but the folder is not existing

Comment: How do you run the node-template?

Comment: By this  ./target/release/node-template --dev --tmp --ws-external --rpc-external

Comment: Because you are using --dev and --tmp is automatically deleting the chain data when stop the node

Comment: I edited the answer with more information

Comment: But when i use this command to run the node-template ./target/release/node-template --dev,it gives me error connecting to substrate (connection to websocket failed).                                                                                                                         But when i use this command ./target/release/node-template --dev --tmp --ws-external --rpc-external  it connects to substrate.

Comment: The answer from Alex above is correct for the message you are seeing and the question in your original post. It seems you have a deeper question. I recommend you open a new post, and spend time to explain what you are trying to do, the what you have tried, and specifically what you expect to happen. Please reivew https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can we proceed with next steps in the substrate documentation without purging the old chain data.